# How to avoid mouse pointer flicker when capture a window by FFmpeg?

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, video-capture

I used gdigrab for capture a window. it works well, But the mouse pointer blinks. (Especially when the window size is large)

My commands (c#):

```
 Process FFProc= new Process();
 FFProc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 FFProc.StartInfo.Arguments="/C ffmpeg -y -f gdigrab -framerate 25 -i title=\"MyWin\" out.mpg";
 FFProc.Start();
```

or (c++):

```
 system("ffmpeg -y -f gdigrab -framerate 25 -i title=\"MyWin\" out.mpg");
```

Please tell me How to avoid mouse pointer flicker when capture a window by FFmpeg?

FFmpeg = latest [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/) build

OS = MS Windows 8.1

Answer (score 3):

Once long ago - in Windows 3.x - the mouse cursor was rendered in software, and it flickered, got stuck when the cooperatively multi-tasked operating system was busy, and was otherwise very limited.

Later, near the introduction Windows 95, Video cards were introduced to 'accelerate' Windows operations. These video cards supported hardware accelerated bitblt's and a hardware mouse cursor. The response of the mouse was very smooth and it supported a drop shadow.

Video cards went through several evolutions and 3D acceleration became more important. The 2D hardware was dropped in favor of more generic 3D support, and mouse cursors with trails, and/or alpha blended drop shadows became popular.

This means that things went full circle, and mouse cursors are software rendered again, but with multitasked operating systems none of the drawbacks of the first time around.

But, because the mouse is actually rendered onto the display, in order to capture a clean screen shot, the mouse cursor must be removed. The cursor is, or was, implemented as a layered window.

The upshot of all of this is, if you obtain a window's DC (via GetDCEx) and copy from it without hiding the cursor, you will get the cursor in the resulting screen cap.

To capture the screen without the cursor flickering you would need to switch to a hardware cursor, and I just don't think that is supported any more.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. find this file (like `avdevice.dll`):

   [image]
2. open it with any hexeditor.
3. find special hex code (`20 00 cc 40`):

   [image]
4. fix hex `40` to `00`:

   [image]

The above is equivalent to:
gdigrap.c in ffmpeg

[image]

***ADD:***

**THE REAL IS THAT this flicker caused by mouser pointer movings behavor in windows leak code**

moved to -1,-1

[image]

move back

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what this is doing exactly, and why this solves OP's question?

Comment: remove const CAPTUREBLT from BitBlt's params

Comment: Worked like a charm for me!